# I need Mutiple fields from both models in an m2m .csv export

Tags: django, django-views

I have a working solution for exporting a .csv file from a join of 2 models via a manytomany relationship and my issue is I don't know how to express, in code, how to bring in multiple fields from the model that is being joined. I can add multiple columns from the model that has the m2m field defined but I can only bring in one column from the model that is being referenced. How do I bring in multiple coulmns from both models?

**models.py**

```
class dbmobile(models.Model):
    Site_Code = models.CharField('Site Code', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, choices=SITE)
    Account_Number = models.CharField('Account Number', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True,)
    Mobile_Number = models.CharField('Mobile_Number', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True,)
    User_Name = CharField('User Name', max_length=120, blank=True, null=True,)
    User_id = models.CharField('User Id', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True,)

class expense(models.Model):
    ExcludeTax = models.DecimalField('Exclude Tax', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    IncludeTax = models.DecimalField('Include Tax', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(dbmobile, blank=True)
    Date = models.DateField(default=now)
```

**views.py**

```
def export_csv(request):  
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')  
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.csv"'  
    employees = expense.objects.all()

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow (['Date', 'Tax Included', 'User'])


    for e in employees:  
        writer.writerow([e.Date, e.IncludeTax, ', '.join([e.User_Name for e in e.user.all()]),])
    return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code around to include the queryset from the parent definition and replaced the join with double underscores on the fields from the parent database and now its working.

**views.py**

```
def expense_table(request):
    item = expense.objects.all().order_by('IncludeTax')
    search_list = expense.objects.all().order_by('user__Site_Code', 'Date')
    search_filter = expenseFilter(request.GET, queryset=search_list)
    add = search_filter.qs.aggregate(Sum('IncludeTax'))['IncludeTax__sum']
    return render(request, 'expense/MExpense.html', {'item': item, 'filter': search_filter, 'add': add})

def export_csv(request):
    employees = expense.objects.all()
    search = expenseFilter(request.GET, queryset=employees).qs
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')  
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.csv"'  
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow (['Date', 'Include Tax', 'User'])
    for e in search.values_list('Date', 'IncludeTax', 'user__Site_Code', 'user__User_id'):
        writer.writerow(e)  
    return response
```